# Make a collection with movies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I need to make a collection with a lot of movies, but I was wondering if there is something like API or other method to make that database automatically? I will be using Ruby on Rails, but if there is a useful and fast tool, I will use it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a 85K record flat file here (called film, not movie): http://download.freebase.com/datadumps/2009-12-30/browse/

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's product API lets you search by category/text. Use that. It will tell you everything about the movie (director, actors, etc). They have that info because Amazon own IMDB.